# Error from gawk about backslash line ending when running configure script

Tags: awk, mingw, config, gawk

I am getting an error when compiling sqlcipher. I'm unable to run ./configure

Could someone help fix the error?

> gawk: /mkopcodeh.awk:101: backslash not last character on line.

[image]

Comment: Does that file use MS-DOS or Unix line endings?

Comment: @CL 
I don ' t know. I lowered the git clone sqlcipher (official source). Compiles on windows with MinGW

Comment: @user628298 - In the future, please don't move the question around; rather ask another question. As you can see, there are no answers for your original question (detailed in the title and struck through in the body); but there are answers to the edited question (which is not detailed in the title). I'm going to rollback the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this: the awk error seems to be caused by different line endings. If you check out the sources on Windows, take care to not have the line endings changed to Windows CR/LF. Instead, stick to LF (Unix/Mac format) only. You can also change the encoding of the offending file with any decent editor later on (I just did with Notepad++ using the menu item Edit->EOL conversion).